Invalid csrf token at doubleCsrf
Need help, can't figure out why Set-Cookie is not being passed to the subsequent requests. If I'm able to do so I think the authentication will work.
Error message:
ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
    at doubleCsrf (D:\GitHub\CSRF\cloned\antiforgerytoken-sample\node_modules\csrf-csrf\lib\cjs\index.cjs:32:61)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\GitHub\CSRF\cloned\antiforgerytoken-sample\express.js:12:5)        
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)       
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Repository:
https://github.com/Codename2200/antiforgerytoken-sample/tree/main

based on bunch of articles that I read, it seems like it is impossible to read Set-Cookie from client side when HttpOnly is set. The DoubleCsrf package is using HttpOnly.
